# One vs someone, can be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice, indefinite-pronouns

I've been searching about the ability to use "one" and "someone" interchangeably but found almost nothing. So what's the difference between them and can they be used interchangeably, **for example**, in these sentences:

- There are numerous things (one, someone) could notice
- There is a hidden place (one, someone) might find
- If (one, someone) comes up to you and asks....

Comment: You probably want to read up on [indefinite pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun).

Comment: They're not *completely* interchangeable. It's much more likely that *one* will be used as a circumspect/euphemistic reference for *the speaker*, or *the person being addressed by the speaker*. We don't normally use *someone* in that way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, can you please give me example?

Comment: [***One** might think **someone** would have](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one+might+think+someone+would+have%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) posted a more complete answer by now.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers One means "me" (Alex)?

Comment: @ Alex: In my preceding comment, *one* would normally be understood to mean *me* (FumbleFingers), *you* (Alex), or *us* (both). One (definitely ***me*** this time! :) might think you'd be more likely to get a proper answer if you'd asked this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). If you "flag" your question with a comment asking for it to be migrated to ELL I'm sure a mod would do that for you.

Comment: How do you "searching about the ability"?  Did you read the dictionary entry for each?

Comment: Oops, my last comment should say "How were you 'searching...'".  Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a grammatical name for the third-person 'you'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341988/is-there-a-grammatical-name-for-the-third-person-you)

Answer (score 2):

They are not interchangeable in meaning, although either one forms a grammatically correct sentence in your examples.

> One might think someone would have posted a more complete answer by now.

This "*One*" is, a 'generic you'.   It refers to *a* generic/unspecified person.   'One' referred to FF when he wrote that, and to me when I read it, and to you when you read it (seperately to *each one* of us, not to all of us a a class of 'ones who tink that ...').

This "*someone*" is a 'generic specific' individual.  When 'the "*one*"' in this sentence *anticipates* a resolution, he thinks "Won't someone do something?   *A person* could have posted a more complete answer by now".   If this answer that I'm writing is "more complete" (or if we ignore "more complete", and just anticipate "an answer"), then I have chosen to *be that someone*.

For a more thorough, formal approach, see the links posted in the comments (by tchrist and FumbleFingers).   Also from FF, you will likely be better served at ELL (this is ELU).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I didn't do that. what's FF?

Comment: @Alex By "FF", I meant "FumbleFingers", the user who posted comments to yor question.  Sorry, it might have been clearer if I had not abbreviated that.