# Is there a grammatical name for the third-person 'you'?

Tags: terminology, personal-pronouns, grammatical-person

I've had this conversation several times in my life, where I use a second-person pronoun when actually using the third-person:

> "If you were dressed up as a clown at night holding black balloons, I would be suspicious too!"
> "I would never dress like a clown."

Or exempting the 'if' from the sentence:

> "You choose to join the organization, then you're responsible for that organization's beliefs and policies."
>
> "I am not a member of that organization"

It's actually hard to come up with examples for this off the top of my head. The point is that I use 'you' as a third person pronoun because it's hypothetical, but it's taken literally, and I want to be able to tell the person I'm talking to what the name of the grammatical construct is so that he or she doesn't misunderstand me.

Comment: It's not third person. It refers to an indefinite person, but it takes second person agreement, not third person.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is it called when using 'you' in place of anyone or yourself in example?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312140/what-is-it-called-when-using-you-in-place-of-anyone-or-yourself-in-example)

Comment: Gotta love that overly excessive bureaucracy inherent to Stack Exchange putting an answered question on hold.

Comment: @JohnLawler it takes a second person pronoun but is not referring to the second person (the actual you) in this case. If the pronoun isn't referring to I, then it is being used as a third person.

Comment: No, person is a grammatical concept, and depends on inflection. If it takes second-person inflection, it's second-person. What it refers to is irrelevant. German _Sie_ is in fact third person plural, though it's used for polite 'you'; similarly, _Usted_ in Spanish is also third person, despite the same meaning. Rather like _Your Majesty_ and _His Majesty_ both being third person. Third person is more polite than second, so it's often used for polite (i.e, catering to nobles) 2nd person.

Comment: 'Gotta love that overly excessive bureaucracy inherent to Stack Exchange putting an answered question on hold. '  Is ELU supposed to keep answering the same questions again and again? 'Overly excessive [sic] bookkeeping' here is actually _trying to keep the site tidy and searchable_.

Comment: Then it should be marked as a duplicate of a question with an accepted answer, not put on hold @EdwinAshworth. There is no justification for putting a question on hold (or closed as it is now) when it has two very good answers and one of them is accepted. 15 people agree with me.

Comment: I did [a search for "generic you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=%22generic%20you%22) and out of all the results, searching by Relevance, the answer to my question shows up in the #2 spot. With 15 votes it far outstrips all of the other questions, because my question was worded the best.

Comment: I agree that the reason given is incorrect. I voted using the duplicate CV reason, you'll notice. But the question has certainly been answered before, so this should be closed. And some people seem to disagree with your opinion of your better wording. The duplicate didn't attract any 'unclear what you're asking' close-votes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it's called "[generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)."
From Wikipedia:

> In English grammar and in particular in casual English, generic you,
>   impersonal you or indefinite you is the pronoun you in its use in
>   referring to an unspecified person, as opposed to its use as the
>   second person pronoun.
>
> The generic you is primarily used as a
>   colloquial or less formal substitute for one.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)[2] For instance,
>
> ```
> "Brushing one's teeth is healthy."
> ```
>
> can be expressed less formally as
>
> ```
> "Brushing your teeth is healthy."
> ```

Comment: This was accepted as the answer but I believe @Rhidian's "impersonal pronoun" is the correct and better answer.

Comment: ["***One** does not simply walk into Mordor*"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor).

Comment: @P.Obertelli Thank you for setting a good example by editing the answer to include the expected information.

Answer (score 18):

This is called an *impersonal pronoun*, and it is equivalent to using *one*. It is just a convention we have in English that we can use the second person pronoun in this context.

Other languages have other conventions for referring to a person as a generic object, and may not use the second person at all.

Comment: I was thinking 'one' as well.

Comment: I believe 'you' is being used as an [impersonal pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/impersonal_pronoun), but generic you is more specific.

Comment: Fair point, I guess 'they' is also an impersonal pronoun but not an instance of generic you, so it depends on how general the OP wanted the definition to be.